# convert from string to list

Tags: prolog

I am starting to play with prolog and have this question:
how can I write this in prolog

```
convert(this is the first program.,S) --> S = [this,is,the,first,program].
```

I tried something like this:

```
convert(Wordlist):-
get0(Char),
getrest(Char,Wordlist).

getrest(46,[]):-!. %end of sentence

getrest(32,Wordlist):-!, %end of word scip and continue
convert(Wordlist).

getrest(Letter,[Word|Wordlist]):-
getletters(Letter,Letters,Nextchar),   %read letters of current word
name(Word,Letters),
getrest(Nextchar,Wordlist).

getletters(46,[],46):-!.
getletters(32,[],32):-!.

getletters(Let,[Let|Letters],Nextchar):-
get0(Char),
getletters(Char,Letters,Nextchar).
```

and it works but I don't get the sentence that I want to convert in the clause like `convert(the first program.,S).` In the solution above I must read the string from the prolog console.

Comment: Find out what a Prolog string is and how it is notated and use a string as an argument in the predicate you are trying to write.

Comment: I try to use a string as an argument but the problem in the get0(Char)   I think that i must use another function instead of get0() but i really don't Know how......

Comment: If you have the string in the argument you do not want to read it from the terminal. Instead you should go through the string one character at a time and doing the same with it as if it was read from the terminal. For this you must know how to visit a list in Prolog using recursion.